# emacs is blocking logout?

Tags: emacs

I've closed all my applications but whenever I tried to shut down, the message always pops up. I feel like there is some process running in the background, how exactly do I terminate that process by emacs?

Comment: How do you try to shut down? Which Desktop environment are you in? You can check if emacs has child process running with `pstree`. You can kill emacs and it's children with `killall emacs`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what message?